# Python regex based split

Tags: python, regex

What would be the best way to split the below string `"(x=1, y = 2, z = 3 )  (a = 1) (m = 4, n = 6, o = 2)"` to extract the key value pairs into any form (list, dict etc.) ? I am interested in (x, 1) (y, 2) (z, 3) etc..

None of the below regex (for extracting info in between parenthesis)

```
>>> re.findall('(.+)(.+)(.+)', '(abc)(def)(ghi)')
[('(abc)(def)(gh', 'i', ')')]
>>> re.findall('(.+)(.+)(.*)', '(abc)(def)(ghi)')
[('(abc)(def)(ghi', ')', '')]
>>> re.findall('(.+)(.+)(.+)', '(abc)(def)(ghi)')
[('(abc)(def)(gh', 'i', ')')]
>>> re.findall('(.+)(.+)(.)', '(abc)(def)(ghi)')
[('(abc)(def)(gh', 'i', ')')]
>>> re.findall('(.+)(.+)(...)', '(abc)(def)(ghi)')
[('(abc)(def)(', 'g', 'hi)')]
>>> re.findall(r'(.+)(.+)(...)', '(abc)(def)(ghi)')
[('(abc)(def)(', 'g', 'hi)')]
>>> re.findall(r'(.+)(.+)(.+)', '(abc)(def)(ghi)')
[('(abc)(def)(gh', 'i', ')')]
>>> re.findall(r'(.+)(.+)(.+?)', '(abc)(def)(ghi)')
[('(abc)(def)(gh', 'i', ')')]
>>> re.findall(r'(.*?)(.*?)(.+?)', '(abc)(def)(ghi)')
```

EDIT: Apologize for not being clear, the grouping is also important here like `[('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 3)], [('a', 1)], [('m', 4), ('n' 6), ('o', 2)]`

Comment: What did you try? Please show your code.

Comment: is this a complete example? or is it possible that any sensible x=y mapping format is present? e.g. (x=y, ..){a=b;...}

Comment: Is there any information in the groupings that shouldn't be discarded?

Comment: @rednaw I am new to regexes, tried a bunch of things, didn't seem to work out.

Comment: The question is too open. I mean, would there be nested structures like `(x = 1, (a = 2, b = 3), z = 2)` ? Also what in the world have you tried ? It's not common sense to just ask for code without any efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in one regex because you want a nested structure as a result. Regex matches are always flat.

However with two regexes it is pretty easily done:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

thestr = "(x=1, y = 2, z = 3 ) (a = 1) (m = 4, n = 6, o = 2)"
groups = re.findall(r'\([^)]+\)', thestr)
matches = []

for group in groups:
    matches.append(re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*=\s*(\d+)', group))

pprint(matches)
```

Will output:

```
[[('x', '1'), ('y', '2'), ('z', '3')],
 [('a', '1')],
 [('m', '4'), ('n', '6'), ('o', '2')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string syntax is never wrong:

```
re.findall('([a-z]+)\s*=\s*([0-9]+)', 
           "(x=1, y = 2, z = 3 ) (a = 1) (m = 4, n = 6, o = 2)")
```

You could also you `finditer`, if you prefer an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to extract all the words and numbers then `zip()` them there afterwards use the `dict()` function to make a dictionary

So Try this:

```
import re
string = "(x=1, y = 2, z = 3 ) (a = 1) (m = 4, n = 6, o = 2)"

stripped = ''.join(re.findall('\w+',string))
words= re.findall('\D+',stripped)
numbers= map(int,re.findall('\d+',string))
print dict(zip(words,numbers))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'm': 4, 'o': 2, 'n': 6, 'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
```

## EDIT:

as you've stated that grouping is important I suggest you to just zip them only as dictionaries are not ordered.

```
print zip(words,numbers)
#[('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 3), ('a', 1), ('m', 4), ('n', 6), ('o', 2)]
```

However you can use a `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

print OrderedDict(zip(words,numbers))
#OrderedDict([('x', '1'), ('y', '2'), ('z', '3'), ('a', '1'), ('m', '4'), ('n', '6'), ('o', '2')])
```

Comment: OP - numbers stored as numbers or strings?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris the "numbers" were already stored as part of one string

Comment: @ChristopherHarris well fixed that

Comment: Why the downvote downvoter? So I Can Improve my answer...

Comment: I don't think this is a very bullet proof method. What if a value is missing? (eg `x=`) Also the result should be nested (as the OP mentioned after his question edit)

Comment: @rednaw nested? *beautiful is better than ugly dude*, if a value is missing this would still work!

Comment: If you would change `(x=1, y = 2, z = 3 ) (a = 1) (m = 4, n = 6, o = 2)` to for example `(x=1, y = 2, z =  ) (a = 1) (m = 4, n = 6, o = 2)`, this script's output would be: `{'m': 4, 'za': 1, 'o': 2, 'n': 6, 'y': 2, 'x': 1}`

Comment: @rednaw how do you suggest it look like and your don't work with that either **:lol!:**  and umm see my edit too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Full code ready to roll:

```
>>> import re
>>> pairs = "(x=1, y = 2, z = 3 ) (a = 1) (m = 4, n = 6, o = 2)"
>>> pairs_map = [(m[1], m[2]) for m in re.findall(r"((\w+)\s*\=\s*(\w+))", pairs)]
>>> pairs_map
[('x', '1'), ('y', '2'), ('z', '3'), ('a', '1'), ('m', '4'), ('n', '6'), ('o', '2')]
>>> dict(pairs_map)
{'a': '1', 'm': '4', 'o': '2', 'n': '6', 'y': '2', 'x': '1', 'z': '3'}
```

Should be straight forward. It matches all occurrences of

`word` `maybe whitespace` `=` `maybe whitespace` `word`